# Stream an MP4 file via HTTP in a QuickTime-compatible format using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, quicktime

QuickTime supports streaming from an HTTP server, for instance try opening `https://ia801307.us.archive.org/18/items/kontikipart2/kontikipart2.mp4` via *File -> Open Location*.

However, streaming the same file to QuickTime from the `http://localhost:8080/kontikipart2.mp4` URL on a local FFmpeg HTTP server launched with the following command

```
ffmpeg -i kontikipart2.mp4 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -pix_fmt yuv420p -listen 1 http://localhost:8080/kontikipart2.mp4
```

or without re-coding

```
ffmpeg -i kontikipart2.mp4 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -c:v copy -c:a copy -listen 1 http://localhost:8080/kontikipart2.mp4
```

results in the `The document “kontikipart2.mp4” could not be opened. The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player.` error, even though the stream can be opened normally in VLC.

Is there a way to launch a QuickTime-compatible HTTP server with FFmpeg?